# $\lim \limits_{\left(x,\:y,\:z\right)\to \left(0,\:0,\:0\right)}\left(\frac{xyz}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Calculate the limit if it exists or prove it doesn´t.

a) $\lim \limits_{\left(x,y\right)\to \left(0,0\right)}\left(\frac{8x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4}\right)$

b) $\lim \limits_{\left(x,\:y,\:z\right)\to \left(0,\:0,\:0\right)}\left(\frac{xyz}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)$

a) was easy to prove it doesn't exist making $y=mx$

in b) i think it is $0$ but i can't prove it

Comment: If you divide the numerator and denominator by $xyz$, you are left with the expression $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{y^2z^2}+\frac{1}{x^2z^2}+\frac{1}{x^2y^2}}}$, which tends to zero as $(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\le1.
$$

Comment: Too concise, but still useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use spherical coordinates:
$x=r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)$, $y=r\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$, $z=r\cos(\theta)$
$$\lim \limits_{\left(x,\:y,\:z\right)\to \left(0,\:0,\:0\right)}\left(\frac{xyz}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)=\lim \limits_{r\to 0}\frac{r^3\sin^2(\theta)\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)\cos(\phi)}{r}$$
which is $0$ since the trigonometric functions appearing are bounded.